# Heroku: How Can I Stop My Postgres Databases from Disappearing after a few minutes?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

Yesterday I uploaded a Rails 5 application with multiple databases to Heroku. I have a hobby-dev postgres add-on. This morning I successfully imported my 7 Postgres databases using pg_dump backups created according to the Heroku documentation.

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump

heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump' HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL
```

Several times I have imported these databases because after a few minutes they disappear. I ran my Heroku app and the first database was successfully accessed but by the time I tried to access the second one I received a 'relation "xxxx" does not exist'. When I went back to my datastore the databases were gone. When I tried to run my app a second time I got a 'relation "xxxx" does not exist' on the first table that I successfully accessed the previous time I ran my app.

I'm not seeing any errors when I look at the data-store for the database. They just disappear. I checked to see if there was a limit to the number of databases I could have with the hobby-dev but did not see any. The row count is under 10,000. Each time I have imported my pg_dump files I get a warning email about the number of rows.

UPDATE 2/17/2017 10:42 AM central: The only thing I have found so far are some posts stating that the Heroku filesystem is ephemeral, and does not persist between dyno restarts. If this is my problem:

1. How do I know when dynos restart if I don't restart it? I had not restarted my app when my databases disappeared.
2. How can I permanently store my databases using the Postgres add-on or do I have to store my databases elsewhere? Surely the add-on has a way to permanently store databases.

Comment: I assume you use Heroku PostgreSQL offering (instead of trying to set it up on your own). If that's the case the ephemeral nature of dyno file systems shouldn't be your concern. I recommend that you first create the seven (empty) databases and see if they disappear or not. You can create a single database with `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`. After each call run `heroku pg:wait` to wait until the database has been provisioned. If the databases don't disappear try restoring your backups then.

Comment: @GregNavis, yes I am. I'm so used to using postgres.app where I deal with things at the server level. Now I understand how the Heroku PostgreSQL add-on works. I will do that and post my results.

Comment: @GregNavis please put your comment as an answer and I will check it.

Comment: Done. Thanks, Pamela. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use Heroku PostgreSQL offering (instead of trying to set it up on your own). If that's the case the ephemeral nature of dyno file systems shouldn't be your concern.

I recommend that you first create the seven (empty) databases and see if they disappear or not. You can create a single database with

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

After each call run `heroku pg:wait` to wait until the database has been provisioned. If the databases don't disappear try restoring your backups then.

Comment: I was so used to working with postgres at the server level I was trying to load all seven databases into one add-on thinking the add on was a server. I created seven add-ons and restored them with my backups. They are working just fine. Thanks!